# Why does a large 12 V battery deplete quicker than 3 small AAA batteries

Tags: battery-operated, usb-device

I have an alarm in my shed.
It takes 3 AAA batteries and these last about 3 months.

Since the alarm has a USB socket input, I decided I could remedy this with a larger battery and power it from there.

I bought some parts:

1. 12 V, 7 Ah "suitable for Security Alarm & Intruder Alarm" battery
2. 5 V, 4.2 A USB car charger (With LED - maybe important)

I fully charged the battery overnight and plugged in the USB car socket and then plugged it into the alarm. It all seemed to work fine.

Three weeks later, the battery was dead.

I charged the battery longer this time and tried again ... same result.

Where has my admittedly shallow knowledge of batteries / electronics failed me?

Why do 3 tiny little AAA's last 4 times longer?

Comment: Are your AAA also plugging in through the USB Socket?

Comment: Which voltage of AAAs is cause of beep? And which voltage of 12V battery is cause of shut down you USB car charger?

If you alarm is nominally working on 5V but still can work on 2V and you car charger shut down on 11.5V - it may be the cause.

Comment: @DKNguyen the AAA batteries sit inside the device when used. The 12v battery is plugged in via the usb socket.

Comment: @Arseniy sorry I may have confused things with my backstory. I will remove irrelevant information.

Comment: @Kohan That might be why. It might be going powering up something else when going through the USB like a processor meant for communications that is normally powered down (why is there a USB in an alarm anyways? What is it used for?) Although, it is still somewhat perplexing since 7Ah dwarfs the AAA batteries though quite believable if we actually knew more about the current draw of the charger and alarm when it was just idling versus when some processor was booted up.

Comment: @DKNguyen the car socket does have a LED that illuminates it which is quite annoying and wondered if that could be cause for the additional drain. I had not considered what the USB socket could be used for. I should check the manual. Thanks.

Comment: How much power does the charger use by itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's see. Assuming the manufacturer isn't lying, the 12 V battery has 7 Ah, that makes 84 Wh, which would translate to 16.8 Ah at the 5 V end at 100% efficiency.

Let's be generous and assume the car charger has an 80% efficiency (they usually aren't very good with low currents); that leaves 13.4 Ah.

If the LED pulls 10 mA, it would, *on its own*, drain the battery in 13.4 / 0.01 = 1344 hours or 56 days. This does not include self-discharge of the battery, the power consumption of the car charger itself, or the alarm's power consumption.

I would remove the LED and try again. Also, a more efficient DC/DC converter (which is the main bit in the car charger) would make a big difference.

Comment: Thank you, this explains a lot. It seems my lego brick approach to solving this problem has failed me. I need to do a lot more research.

Answer (score 3):

The USB charger draws 14mA off load. which is relevant to the 7Ah in 3 weeks.
So the consumption of your alarm is too low compared to the effeiciency of the usb charger.

Comment: I would agree with this if the 14mA number were actually coming from somewhere.

Comment: I tested once a usb charger. Nothing says that all are the same but since 7Ah on 12v for 3 weeks is 13.88 mA I guess it is right for this one also.